Cloudwatch insights sorting fields with leading digits
I have a structured log at includes vehicle identification numbers (VIN); what I want is a list of matching records, ordered by the VIN that appears in the log.
The documentation of I have found reads

Use sort to display log events in ascending (asc) or descending (desc) order by a specified field.

So my query looks like
sort by vin asc

and my results look like:
3FMCR9G64RRE74382
3FTTW8F94PRA24621
5J8TC2H38RL009010
5N1AT3CA4MC708138
19XFL2H86RE022063
58AFZ1B10RU178691
JF1VBAF66N9022448
JM3KFADM8M0422587

Presumably because 3 < 5 < 19 < 58 < J ?!
Is there a documented method for either defining the field or controlling the sort order so that 19XFL2H86RE022063 appears as the first entry in the results?

It looks like there is no "by" keyword in the CloudWatch sort syntax
Try using just sort vin asc and see if that works for you.

Updated documentation for this sort function is available at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax-Sort.html
Summary:

All non-number values come before all number values. Number values are values that include only numbers, not a mix of numbers and other characters.
For non-number values, the algorithm groups consecutive numeric characters and consecutive alphabetic characters into separate chunks for comparison. It orders non-numeric portions by their Unicode values, and it orders numeric portions by their length first and then by their numerical value.

